# Upgrading PostgreSQL database with cstore_fdw

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, cstore-fdw

I am attempting to upgrade a PostgreSQL database from 11.2 to 12.2, and it has the cstore_fdw extension on it.  From what I can tell, this is not supported, so I migrated all cstore foreign tables to native tables, dropped the extension:

```
create schema cstore_backup;

-- executed the results of all of these:

select
  format ('create table cstore_backup.%s_%s as select * from %s.%s;',
  foreign_table_schema, foreign_table_name,
  foreign_table_schema, foreign_table_name)
from information_schema.foreign_tables ft 
where foreign_server_name = 'cstore_server';

select
  format ('drop foreign table %s.%s;',
  foreign_table_schema, foreign_table_name)
from information_schema.foreign_tables ft 
where foreign_server_name = 'cstore_server';

DROP SERVER cstore_server;

drop extension cstore_fdw;
```

I deleted the folders (I'll put them back to cstore after migration):

```
rm -fr /apps/pgdata11.2.0/cstore_fdw
rm -f /usr/local/psql11.2/share/postgresql/extension/cst*
```

I removed references from the postgresql.conf file.

When I run pg_upgrade:

```
$BIN/pg_upgrade \
  --old-bindir=/usr/local/psql11.2/bin \
  --new-bindir=/usr/local/psql12.2/bin \
  --old-datadir=/apps/pgdata11.2.0 \
  --new-datadir=/apps/pgdata12.2.0 \
  --old-port=5432 \
  --new-port=5432 \
  --jobs=4 --link --username=postgres --check
```

I still get this message in the loadable_libraries.txt output file:

> could not load library
>   "/usr/local/psql11.2/lib/postgresql/cstore_fdw.so": ERROR:  could not
>   load library "/usr/local/psql11.2/lib/postgresql/cstore_fdw.so":
>   /usr/local/psql11.2/lib/postgresql/cstore_fdw.so: undefined symbol:
>   ExecClearTuple

I'm stumped.  Where does cstore_fdw still reside in my installation?

Comment: Is the `cstore_fdw` extension still installed in another database in the cluster? If you don't have any other user-created databases, it could be in `postgres` or `template1`.

Comment: The library will be loaded if you refer any of the functions defined in the extension, see anywhere you are referring it(like in trigger or custom data types).
Also, As @NickBarnes mentioned, make sure that extension is not installed in any of the databases in the same instance/cluster. 
Also double-check that `shared_preload_libraries` is not set in postgresql.conf

Comment: Thanks, both, for the comments.  It is not installed in any other database, and I did remove it from postgresql.conf before attempting the upgrade.  I appreciate the suggestions.  I'm about ready to uninstall and re-install 11.2 and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions...  it turns out there were some leftover functions in the public schema that referenced the extension, even though it was completely gone.  I found all of them with this:

```
select * from pg_proc where prosrc ilike '%cstore%'
```

Dropping each of them resolved the issues.

```
drop function public.cstore_clean_table_resources(oid);
drop function public.cstore_ddl_event_end_trigger();
drop function public.cstore_drop_trigger();
drop function public.cstore_fdw_handler();
drop function public.cstore_fdw_validator(text[], oid);
drop function public.cstore_table_size(relation regclass);
```